# Birthday input field - auto-adding dots after specific amount of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Hey guys,
unusual question: I have a input field #birthday that should accept european date format like this. dd.MM.yyyy

I wonder if it is possible to auto apply dots when typed into this field.

Imagine the inputfield is focused and empty. I start typing to numbers and the field autogenerates a dot, again two numbers and a dot is generated.

My aim is to type only numbers without needing to add the dots.

any idea how i could achieve that with jquery or javascript in general?

```
$('#birhtday').keypress(function() {
    // ?
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use existing jQuery plugins?

- [Masked input](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maskedinput)
- [meioMask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) - I find it nicer because it doesn't use those underscores (but it seems to have some bugs when <kbd>TAB</kbd>ing through filled form)